# Not able to connect to mysql db on lightsail in spring boot

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I have installed mysql on ubuntu os on amazon lightsail. I have uploaded fat jar on lightsail server. I have mysql configuration in application.properties file as spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydbname?useSSL=false
but not able to connect to mysql db running locally on lightsail. tried with public ip also but no success.

Comment: Dumb question: Is mysql running on the machine?  It doesn't automatically get started when installed and doesn't get automatically flagged to start on boot.

Comment: See if you can log in via the mysql client from the Lightsail command line. Should be mysql -u <username> -p 

It will prompt for a password

If you can do that, then the problem is in your application code, if you cannot decide if it's because you have the wrong credentials or if MySQL is not actually running.

Comment: @MikeColeman I can execute mysql commands from lighsail instance that I created and mySql is in running state. I checked it using status command of ubuntu.As you suggested, I already tried connecting through mysql client with public ip provided for that instance. I doubt for firewall configurations required to allow external traffic.

Comment: @DavidG it might be a dumb question for people like you,but we are new to this technology and I am trying to get some help from people who are ready to do it. If you feel that people like me asking dumb question you just ignore it and dont make any comments.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't saying YOU were asking a dumb question ... I was saying that my question to you might be dumb.